# Earthing a Cat6a shielded home setup

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm in the UK and I've installed Cat6a U/FTP shielded cable in my home - yes, I know! I now realise this wasn't necessary and should have just gone with UTP!

But I would really appreciate some advice on terminating the connections and sanity check what I intend on purchasing to complete the setup. Even a quick answer to question 4 would be great!

I have a data cabinet next to the gas and electric metres in my home. The electricity mains supply earth cable is attached to the copper gas piping. I plan to use:

A. A patch panel inside the cabinet with an earth cable and attach the other end to the copper gas piping along with the one coming from the electricity supply

B. Shielded tooless keystone jacks for the patch panel

C. Shielded patch leads from the patch panel to non-rackmounted, unmanaged switches inside the cabinet

D. Unshielded patch leads from the switches to various devices - QNAP NAS, Rasberry pi, routers etc.

E. Unshielded faceplates in bedrooms

F. Unshielded patch leads from the faceplates to end devices - laptops, PC's etc

In as simple as possible laymans terms, but preferably backed by real world experience or actual research or standards:

1. What would, realistically, be the effects of not earthing on either end?
2. The general consensus seems to be that it is best to earth at one end than it is both ends. I've read that earthing at both ends causes problems. Is this correct?
3. Would the above plan - A to F work? What would be better, how much better and why? (I'd like to be able to run at 10gbps one day!)
4. I plan to buy the following items. Would these be suitable for my plan? If not, what would be better?

Patch panel:

https://www.comms-express.com/products/excel-24-port-keystone-v-patch-panel-frame

Tooless keystone jacks:

https://www.comms-express.com/products/excel-cat6a-low-profile-screened-keystone-jack/

SSTP Patch leads for patch panel to switch:

https://www.comms-express.com/products/cat6a-ethernet-cable-patch-leads-sstp-lsoh-booted/

Switches:

https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS108v4.aspx
https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS116v2.aspx

Faceplates:

https://www.comms-express.com/products/4x-rj45-cat6-modules-in-doublegang-faceplate/

UUTP Patch leads for faceplate to devices and switches to devices:

https://www.comms-express.com/products/excel-cat6a-ethernet-cable-patch-leads-lsoh-unscreened-u-utp-booted/

Any advice, appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to remove the actual product requests from the question to avoid closure - the rest up to there is perfectly valid. As UK wiring is always a coherent unit, barring separate ring-mains, I'd say so long as one end of every earthable structure is earthed, you've got it. Earthing both ends, potentially over different rings, really shouldn't be an issue because standard UK wiring will strap all the earths together at at some point.. [Commercial may be different, but domestic tends to run earth to all three, water, gas & electric meter] they're all running to "actual dirt".

Comment: You could use non-shielded terminations everywhere, just make sure the shield isn't touching anything and you shouldn't have any issues. At this point, if it was me I would use shielded jacks and an appropriate patch panel and ground there, but no where else, just the old telco tech in me coming out. Do not ground to a gas pipe, copper or otherwise, I know in the US it's against the electrical code to ground anything to a gas pipe, better to use an electric or water ground point, or drive a ground rod outside. Specific brands/models are outside of the realm of recommendations here.

Comment: @acejavelin - we are not discussing the US's hideously over-complicated electrical code. The UK is not the US, by a long stretch when it comes to mains power code. Strapping to electric, gas & water is **standard** not unusual [Separate earthing spikes are optional]. The entire building is wired that way, not just a bit of DIY. Earth is absolutely compulsory & very over-spec'd… & above all, very safe compared to the 'wild west' that makes up US code.

Comment: You don't need shielded cable in your home. If you were wiring in an environment full of EMI, sure, but just because you're near electrical wires in your home.

Comment: OP appears to be aware of that - however, having purchased & installed said shielded cabling.. would like to use it to best advantage.

Comment: @Tetsujin - thank you. Sounds like my plan is all ok then. Although I'm not sure what you mean by "so long as one end of every earthable structure is earthed"? Also, do you have any views on using shielded keystone jacks and patch leads on the patch panel - is this best/necessary?

Comment: @Tetsujin - similarly, would there be any advantages of using shielded faceplates and shielded cables from the faceplates to devices instead of unshielded as I'm currently planning to do?

Comment: "The electricity mains supply earth cable is attached to the copper gas piping" this is irrelevant. That cable is used to earth your gas pipes (not the other way around). See [Earthing Types - DIYWiki](http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/Earthing_Types) for the ways in which your electric supply can be earthed.

Comment: @Tetsujin "Main bonding is the electrical interconnection of incoming (metallic) services (e.g. water, gas, and oil pipes) plus any extraneous conductive parts of a building (like the metal framework used in some buildings, or the central heating pipework), to the main electrical earth. This ensures that under fault conditions things like pipework running through a building are not able to take on a dramatically different electrical potential to that of the installation's earth connection."

Comment: @DavidPostill so do you have any opinion on my plan? I.e. are you suggesting I should attach the earth from the patch panel to something else?

Comment: @richyrich202 No. I was only commenting on the earthing as that is the only bit I know anything about :) Disclaimer: I work for a power company so I am expected to know this stuff :)